# How to set values dynamically in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I create app that render inputs dynamically, some result of calculations I need to set to every block to spans `className="strongCrist"` and `className="strongRuby"`. But sets only same value to all blocks spans. On pure JavaScript it was very simple - in loop we add `innerHTML` to span and add span by `parentElement.appendChild`.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

function PrimaryInputs() {
  const [playersQuantity, setPlayersQuantity] = useState(0);
  const [cristQuantity, setCristQuantity] = useState(0);
  const [rubyQuantity, setRubyQuantity] = useState(0);
  const [isCalculated, setIsCalculated] = useState(false);
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({});
  const [cupsQuantity, setCupsQuantity] = useState(0);
  const [dole, setDole] = useState(0);
  const [doleCrist, setDoleCrist] = useState(0);
  const [doleRuby, setDoleRuby] = useState(0);

  function playersHandleChange(event) {
    setPlayersQuantity(event.target.value);
  }
  function cristHandleChange(event) {
    setCristQuantity(event.target.value);
  }
  function rubyHandleChange(event) {
    setRubyQuantity(event.target.value);
  }
  function iterator(quantity) {
    let elems = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
      elems.push(
        <div
          className={`playersBlock ${isCalculated ? "calculated" : ""} `}
          key={`player${i}`}
        >
          <input
            type="number"
            name={`cupsOf${i}`}
            placeholder="players cups"
            className="plCup"
            onChange={cupsHandleChange}
          />
          <br />
          <span className="strongCrist">Cristalls: {doleCrist}</span>
          <br />
          <span className="strongRuby">Rubies: {doleRuby}</span>
        </div>
      );
    }
    return elems;
  }
  function cupsHandleChange(event) {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setInputs((prev) => {
      return { ...prev, [name]: Number(value) };
    });
    setIsCalculated(true);
  }

  function countCups() {
    let i = 0;
    for (const key in inputs) {
      const val = inputs[key];
      if (val) {
        i += val;
      }
      setCupsQuantity(i);
    }
  }

  function countDole() {
    for (const key in inputs) {
      const val = inputs[key];
      if (val) {
        setDole(val / cupsQuantity);
        setDoleCrist(Math.round(dole * cristQuantity));
        setDoleRuby(Math.round(dole * rubyQuantity));
      }
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    countCups();
    countDole();
  });

  return (
    <>
      <div className="mainInputs">
        <div className="input_wrapper">
          <label htmlFor="players">Enter quantity of players</label>
          <input
            type="number"
            name="players"
            id="players"
            onChange={playersHandleChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="input_wrapper">
          <label htmlFor="cristall">Enter cristalls</label>
          <input
            type="number"
            name="cristall"
            id="allCrist"
            onChange={cristHandleChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="input_wrapper">
          <label htmlFor="ruby">Enter rubies</label>
          <input
            type="number"
            name="ruby"
            id="allRuby"
            onChange={rubyHandleChange}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr />
      <span>
        {playersQuantity ? `players quantity: ${playersQuantity}` : null}
      </span>
      <br />
      <span className="sumCup">
        {cupsQuantity ? `cups quantity: ${cupsQuantity}` : null}
      </span>
      <div id="playersList">{iterator(playersQuantity)}</div>
    </>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <>
    <PrimaryInputs />
  </>,
  document.getElementById("mydiv")
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the behaviour you need, the main thing was to create a separate component for the player, to allow it to have it's own state:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

const int = (value) => {
    let integer = parseInt(value);
    if (isNaN(integer) || integer < 0) integer = 0;
    return integer;
}

//new component player block, to allow each one have it's own value
const PlayerBlock = ({ cristQuantity, rubyQuantity, setTotalCupsQuantity }) => {
    const [doleRuby, setDoleRuby] = useState();
    const [doleCrist, setDoleCrist] = useState();
    const [playerCups, setPlayerCups] = useState(0);


    //ref to access the input
    const ref = useRef();

    //useEffect that will trigger when the parent component's cristQuantity and rubyQuantity change, this is necessary to update the player ruby and cris when they are changed
    useEffect(() => {
        setDoleRuby(int(ref.current.value) * rubyQuantity);
        setDoleCrist(int(ref.current.value) * cristQuantity);
    }, [cristQuantity, rubyQuantity])

    function cupsHandleChange(event) {
        const inputVal = int(event.target.value);

        console.log("inputVal", inputVal);

        setPlayerCups(inputVal);
        setTotalCupsQuantity((previousValue) => {
            previousValue -= playerCups;
            return previousValue + inputVal;
        })
        setDoleRuby(inputVal * rubyQuantity);
        setDoleCrist(inputVal * cristQuantity);
    }

    return <div className={`playersBlock calculated`}>
        <input
            type="number"
            placeholder="players cups"
            className="plCup"
            ref={ref}
            onChange={cupsHandleChange}
        />
        <br />
        <span className="strongCrist">Cristalls: {doleCrist}</span>
        <br />
        <span className="strongRuby">Rubies: {doleRuby}</span>
    </div>
}

export default function PrimaryInputs() {
    const [playersQuantity, setPlayersQuantity] = useState(0);
    const [cristQuantity, setCristQuantity] = useState(0);
    const [rubyQuantity, setRubyQuantity] = useState(0);
    const [totalCupsQuantity, setTotalCupsQuantity] = useState(0);

    function playersHandleChange(event) {
        setPlayersQuantity(int(event.target.value));
    }

    function cristHandleChange(event) {
        setCristQuantity(int(event.target.value));
    }

    function rubyHandleChange(event) {
        setRubyQuantity(int(event.target.value));
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div className="mainInputs">
                <div className="input_wrapper">
                    <label htmlFor="players">Enter quantity of players</label>
                    <input
                        type="number"
                        name="players"
                        id="players"
                        onChange={playersHandleChange}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="input_wrapper">
                    <label htmlFor="cristall">Enter cristalls</label>
                    <input
                        type="number"
                        name="cristall"
                        id="allCrist"
                        onChange={cristHandleChange}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="input_wrapper">
                    <label htmlFor="ruby">Enter rubies</label>
                    <input
                        type="number"
                        name="ruby"
                        id="allRuby"
                        onChange={rubyHandleChange}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr />
            <span>
                {playersQuantity ? `players quantity: ${playersQuantity}` : null}
            </span>
            <br />
            <span className="sumCup">
                {totalCupsQuantity ? `cups quantity: ${totalCupsQuantity}` : null}
            </span>
            <div id="playersList">
                {new Array(playersQuantity).fill().map((el, i) => { //inline way to loop, creates a dummy array with the size of playerquantity, and just loops through it rendering the new component, and passing in the necessary
                    return <PlayerBlock
                        key={`player${i}`}
                        cristQuantity={cristQuantity}
                        rubyQuantity={rubyQuantity}
                        setTotalCupsQuantity={setTotalCupsQuantity} />
                }
                )}
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```